# Restore after `maximize-window`

Tags: window

If I have multiple windows open, I can maximize one using `M-x maximize-window`.

How should I restore the windows to their original size?

Answer (score 2):

One possible way: save the current window configuration to a register, maximize and then when you are done, restore the saved window configuration. E.g. to save it in register `R`: `C-x r w R`; then to restore: `C-x r j R`. These run the commands `window-configuration-to-register` and `jump-to-register` resp. You can look at the doc strings of these functions with `C-h f RET window-configuration-to-register RET` e.g.

Here's a [link to the relevant section of the Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Configuration-Registers.html#Configuration-Registers).